# Update stripe subscription payment card details rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, stripe-payments

I am Using ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux],Rails 5.2.4.4 and Using stripe 5.26.0

I have created stripe subscription

```
 customer = if current_user.stripe_customer_id?
                 Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_customer_id)
               else
                 Stripe::Customer.create({
                                             :email => current_user.email,
                                             :source => params[:stripeToken],
                                             :description => "Tukaweb Stripe Subscriptions customer= #{current_user.email}"
                                         },
                                         {
                                             api_key: Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
                                         }
                 )
               end
    ## check if user have already took the subscription
    if current_user.subscriptions.where(payment_status: 'paid', software_package_id:  @subscription.software_package_id).empty?
      ## with trail period
      subscription = Stripe::Subscription.create({
                                                     customer: customer,
                                                     items: [
                                                         {price: 'price_1HVF68E9ijv19IzXdDVmKN5e'},
                                                     ],
                                                     trial_end: (Time.now + 1.month).to_i,
                                                 })
    else
      ## without trail period
      subscription = Stripe::Subscription.create({
                                                     customer: customer,
                                                     items: [
                                                         {price: 'price_1HVF68E9ijv19IzXdDVmKN5e'},
                                                     ],
                                                 })
    end

    current_user.update({
                            stripe_customer_id: customer.id
                        })
```

Now I want to update stripe subscriptions card details it giving error:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_customer_id)
stripe_subscription = SoftwareUser.find(params[:software_user_id])
subscription = customer.subscriptions.retrieve(stripe_subscription.stripe_subscription_id)
subscription.source = params[:stripeToken]
subscription.save
```

Error as:

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError (Received unknown parameter: source):
```

can you please suggest how to update the card details for a subscription.

Answer (score 1):

This is failing because there is no source attribute on a Subscription.

In this particular case, you're relying on the fact that when the Subscription is created, that it will fall back to using the default source of the Customer to fund the Subscription [1] because there is no default payment method. If you want to change the Source that pays the Subscription, you would have to change the default source of the Customer [2].

All that being said, the recommendation today is not to use Sources at all but rather to create a PaymentMethod [3] using Stripe.js and Elements. You attach this PaymentMethod to the Customer [4] Then you would set this payment method as default on either the Invoice [5], Subscription [6] or Customer [7].

The steps are outlined in more detail here [8].

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=ruby#create_subscription-default_payment_method

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object?lang=ruby#customer_object-default_source

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment

[4] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach?lang=ruby

[5] https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object?lang=ruby#invoice_object-default_payment_method

[6] https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object?lang=ruby#subscription_object-default_payment_method

[7] https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object?lang=ruby#customer_object-invoice_settings-default_payment_method

[8] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#create-subscription

Comment: so to create a payment method, the server need to have the Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard, because for creating payment method server should have the card no. and cvc or there is some js that will give the purpose.

Comment: My apologies, that link to server side PaymentMethod creation was somewhat misleading. The best way to minimize your PCI burden and to make sure that card details are being securely sent to Stripe in a PCI compliant manner, you should use Stripe.js and Elements to tokenize card details or use Stripe Checkout to collect PaymentMethod details. Both approaches are outlined (in relation to subscriptions) in these guides: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#create-subscription  https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout/fixed-price